# How to click on the DIV dropdown values using selenium when there are no <options> kind of tags are coded

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am unable to fetch the elements for options being displayed from a dropdown, where in Source, I couldn't find any options listed.

Element is like following :

```
<div id="trigger-picker" class="x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-default x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger-default "></div>
```

Please help.

Comment: <div id="trigger-picker" class="x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-default x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger-default "></div>

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution:
1. click the dropdown: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#trigger-picker")).click()`
2. after click the dropdown, the options will show, then select the option that you want

Answer (score 0):

There may the problem of wait. You need to wait for the elements to be clickable.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("trigger-picker"))).click()
```

Comment: Problem is not with the dropdown button.. I can click on the dropdown button and get the list.. but the options are dynamic and can't find any element details for the list..